# Azure AD Access token of Client Application does not contain Roles Claims

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, access-token, azure-managed-identity

I have 2 Azure AD applications say `Client-App` and `Server-App` in Azure AD App registrations.

**Server AD Application:**

- Registered a new App in Azure AD.
- Set up App Roles with name "Search.Address" which is custom role.

**Client AD Application:**

- Registered a new App in Azure AD.
- API Permissions: Added the role "Search.Address" created in `server-app` registration is exposed as an Application Permissions in `client app`.
- Granted Admin access successfully.

I have client `Function App` created with .NET stack and enabled system managed identity which is associated with `Client-App`. Client function app runs code to get an access token using `ManagedIdentityCredential`.

Token is successfully created **but role "Search.Address" is missing.**

I tried Client-App exposing as an API. But in no vain.

**Does Managed identity have any permission to talk to server? How I can assign that using `approleassignment` ?**

```
 public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;
            string responseMessage = string.Empty;
            try
            {

               var credential = new ManagedIdentityCredential();
               var accessToken = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new string[] { "SERVERAPP_ClientID/.default" }) { });
               
                responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                    ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                    : $"Hello, {name}. Your Token: {accessToken.Token}";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                log.LogError(ex.Message+ex.InnerException.Message);
            }           

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
```

Reference:

https://anoopt.medium.com/few-ways-of-obtaining-access-token-in-azure-application-to-application-authentication-40a9473a2dde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the application permission/app role to the Managed Identity service principal.
You can't do this through the Portal at the moment, you'll need PowerShell to do that:

```
Connect-AzureAD
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId 1606ffaf-7293-4c5b-b971-41ae9122bcfb -Id 32028ccd-3212-4f39-3212-beabd6787d81 -PrincipalId 1606ffaf-7293-4c5b-b971-41ae9122bcfb -ResourceId c3ccaf5a-47d6-4f11-9925-45ec0d833dec
```

Note that this is for the older AzureAD module. There is also a similar cmdlet for the newer Microsoft.Graph module.

For the AzureAD cmdlet, the ids you need are:

- ObjectId and PrincipalId: Managed Identity Service Principal object ID
- Id: id of the app role/app permission
- ResourceId: object ID of the API Service Principal

Running this command is the same thing as the admin consent for application permissions.

Article I wrote on this: https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions